# How to determine the intersection of 6 planes?

Tags: geometry, 3d, polyhedra

ABCD is a tetrahedron (not necessarly a regular one). A Monge's plane is a plane which is perpendicular to an edge and goes through the middle of the opposite edge.

[image: Monge's plan]

I want to prove that the 6 Monge's planes of this triangle converge in a unique point and I haven't got any idea of the way to do this.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You've tried taking the coordinate geometry route?

Comment: I tried but there are too many unknowns and I don't see how to characterize this kind of conditions.

Comment: The strategy I had in mind was for you to take three of those planes, find their intersection, and then verify that that point lies in those three other planes...

Comment: Okay, this might help you with simplifying things: position your tetrahedron such that one vertex is at the origin and one of the edges lies on an axis. Have one of the faces lie in a coordinate plane, if needed. You might want to use the formulae [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html) to help you with assembling plane equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.geometrie.tuwien.ac.at/havlicek/pub/hoehen.pdf)'s a concise linear algebra proof (pages 5 and 6). And [here's](http://journals.cambridge.org/article_S0013091500002157) a geometrical proof.

Comment: I'm watching this tonight but your second link seems dead...

Comment: Sorry, I grabbed a redirected link that contained a session code. Fixed. By the way, you're *looking at* this tonight. "Watching" is for observing something that may change over time, like a process or a movie or a game or a sunset.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know :) I'm not english ! Thank you.